# Remove partial string from dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
id    str
01    abc_d(a)
02    ab_d(a)
03    abcd_e(a)
04    a_b(a)
```

How can i get a dataframe as following ? Sorry i makeup this dataframe to represent my real issues. Thanks.

```
id    str
01    d
02    d
03    e
04    b
```

Comment: I try, but I can only accept one answer. When i click others, the previous one become gray...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Bad Answer)

#### `Series.str.split` soup

```
df['str'] = df['str'].str.split('(').str[0].str.split('_').str[-1]    
df

   id str
0   1   d
1   2   d
2   3   e
3   4   b
```

---

(Less Bad answer)

#### `Series.str.extract`

```
df['str'] = df['str'].str.extract(r'_([^_]+)\(', expand=False)
df

   id str
0   1   d
1   2   d
2   3   e
3   4   b
```

Regex methods come with their fair share of overhead, and `str.extract`  does not do much to make things better.

---

(Better Answer)

#### `re.search` with list comp

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\()')
df['str'] = [p.search(x)[0] for x in df['str'].tolist()] 
df

   id str
0   1   d
1   2   d
2   3   e
3   4   b
```

This should be faster than the above methods. I find list comprehensions are really fast compared to most vectorised string pandas methods, even if this does use regex. I pre-compile the pattern in advance to alleviate some of the performance concerns.

---

(Also a better answer)

#### `str.split` with list comp

```
df['str'] = [
    x.split('(', 1)[0].split('_')[1] for x in df['str'].tolist()
]
df

   id str
0   1   d
1   2   d
2   3   e
3   4   b
```

This combines the best of both worlds, the performance of a list comp and the speed of pure python string splitting. Should be the fastest.

---

**Performance**

```
df_test = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
%timeit df_test['str'].str.extract(r'_([^_]+)\(', expand=False)
%timeit df_test['str'].str.split('(').str[0].str.split('_').str[-1] 
%timeit [p.search(x)[0] for x in df_test['str'].tolist()] 
%timeit [x.split('(', 1)[0].split('_')[1] for x in df_test['str'].tolist()]

70.4 ms ± 623 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
99.6 ms ± 730 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
31 ms ± 877 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
30 ms ± 431 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)  # fastest but not by much
```

Comment: again coldspeed! if you have time, could you shorlty include an explanation what makes the answers good, bad or better if they convey the same result? I am a beginner and don't see the immediate difference in terms of quality with the exception that your best answer seems be the worst in terms of readability to me (no offence)

Comment: @sudonym yes, give me a minute, I'll add some more info ;-)

Comment: as usual, I am impressed - enjoy your day!

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd choose `str.split('(').str[0].str.split('_').str[-1]` over `str.split('_').str[-1].str[0]`. This doesn't invalidate the rest of your answer, but there's no need to make a splitting approach seem worse than it is.

Comment: @jpp not great for readability but possibly better in terms of lesser number of splits, depending on your string.

Comment: As in, you would need to add n=1 somewhere in there... I've not done that :-(

Comment: Basically I've tried to show the best str split option and argue it's still not great

Answer (score 3):

Using `extract`

```
df['str']=df['str'].str.extract("\_(.*)\(",expand=True) 
df
Out[585]: 
   id str
0   1   d
1   2   d
2   3   e
3   4   b
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try `split` similar to [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings):

```
df['str'] = df['str'].str.split('_').str.get(1).str[0]
```

Or,

```
df['str'] = df['str'].str.split('_').str.get(1).str.split('(').str[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pd.Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html). Specific to your particular format.

```
df['str'] = df['str'].str.split('_').str[-1].str[0]

print(df)

   id str
0   1   d
1   2   d
2   3   e
3   4   b
```